# Interchanging two substrings in a pandas string column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to replace a string with a part of itself in a Pandas DataFrame.

Example:

Change `MSc Joe L. Scott` to `Joe L. Scott MSc`

So only MSc needs to be moved. I can fix this with a regex but don't know how to do this with a Pandas DataFrame

```
result = re.sub(r'(MSc)(.*)' , r'\2 \1',s)
```

I was thinking of something like this (but what's `to_replace` and `value` here?):

```
['Name_modified'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace= **??**, value=**??**)
```

Or using `DataFrame.sub()`

But despite the documentation I do not get it done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a contrived example, consider

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['MSc Joe L. Scott', 'BSc J. Doe']})
df
               Name
0  MSc Joe L. Scott
1        BSc J. Doe
```

You can use `str.replace` here with backreferences. This can easily handle multiple different designations.

```
designations = ['MSc', 'BSc']
df['Name_modified'] = df['Name'].str.replace(
    rf"^({'|'.join(designations)})\s(.*)$", r"\2 \1")

df
               Name     Name_modified
0  MSc Joe L. Scott  Joe L. Scott MSc
1        BSc J. Doe        J. Doe BSc
```

You can assign this result back.

Comment: :Thanks a million!! Is it also possible to read from column `Name` and add it to column `Name_modified` to preserve the original string?